# Variable number of cells over fixed # of columns in VF

Tags: visualforce, dynamic-visualforce

I want to render up to 9 images in a panel, where each image is a commandlink. There is logic in the controller that determines which images/values are appropriate in the given context. I have the following:

```
<apex:outputPanel rendered="{!RequestType == ''}">
        <apex:pageblock title="Resident Requests" mode="maindetail">
            <apex:panelgrid columns="3">
                <apex:repeat value="{!Types}" var="t">
                    <apex:commandLink rerender="all">
                        <apex:param name="type" value="{!t.TypeId}" assignTo="{!RequestType}" />
                        <apex:image url="{!URLFOR($Resource.RequestImages, 'Request_'+t.TypeID+'.png')}" width="202" height="157" />
                    </apex:commandLink>
                </apex:repeat>
            </apex:panelgrid>
        </apex:pageblock>
    </apex:outputPanel>
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work, [because:](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_panelGrid.htm)

> Note that if an `<apex:repeat>` component is used within an
>   `<apex:panelGrid>` component, all content generated by the
>   `<apex:repeat>` component is placed in a single `<apex:panelGrid>`
>   cell.

I also tried putting an `<apex:panelGroup>` inside the repeat, but it still renders the whole series in a single table cell. Any ideas of alternative approaches for this Visualforce newcomer?

Comment: Fixed for now by abandoning the panelgrid and setting the pageblock to a block/div with a width less than 4 of the images wide. Still glad for other thoughts.

Comment: Try `<apex:pageBlockSection columns="3">` and within it repeat your stuff spewing out either the outuputLinks or the `<apex:pageBlockSectionItem>`? I think I did it that way but it was ages ago and I can't look up the code, it's not my property anymore.

Comment: My first thought was ditching `apex:panelgrid` (which renders `<table>`) and using either `apex:outputPanel` in block mode (which renders `<div>`) or just raw `<div>` tags. Just say 'no' to `<table>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could speed up the page's loading time by skipping tables and simply using `span` or `div` tags to help things along. Here's a simple design that gets the job done:

```
<apex:pageblock title="Resident Requests" mode="maindetail">
    <apex:repeat value="{!Types}" var="t">
        <span style="display: inline-block; width: 33%">
            <apex:commandLink rerender="all">
                <apex:param name="type" value="{!t.TypeId}" assignTo="{!RequestType}" />
                <apex:image url="{!URLFOR($Resource.RequestImages, 'Request_'+t.TypeID+'.png')}" width="202" height="157" />
            </apex:commandLink>
        </span>
    </apex:repeat>
</apex:pageblock>
```

Comment: I think you need to delete the apex panelgrid tag from your code.  (Turnabout is fair play.)

Comment: I also get this error when I try your code without the panelgrid: "Error: apex:commandLink must occur between <apex:form></apex:form> tags"

Comment: (1) Good point. I forgot to delete it after I copy-pasted and edited the code. (2) I'd expect this error if you didn't include all of the extra dressing (e.g. a controller, apex:page, etc). This is a snippet that directly emulates the snippet provided in the original question.

Comment: No, the form tags would also be needed for the code to compile in a standard apex page with a controller specified.

Comment: This is along the lines of what  Peter & I discussed in comments above - skipping tables altogether. I did it by fixing the width of the page block to slightly more than 3 x the width of my images, but same deal. HTML-tables--

Answer (score 1):

Here is sample code from a Force.com Labs app that looks like it does what you need:

```
<table border="0" width="100%" id="table4">
<tr>
       <td bgcolor="#C0C0C0"><font face="Arial">Product</font></td>
       <td bgcolor="#C0C0C0"><font face="Arial">Description</font></td>
       <td bgcolor="#C0C0C0"><font face="Arial">Image</font></td>
       <td bgcolor="#C0C0C0"><font face="Arial">Quantity</font></td>
       <td bgcolor="#C0C0C0"><font face="Arial">Unit Price</font></td>
       <td bgcolor="#C0C0C0"><font face="Arial">Total Price</font></td>
</tr>
<tr>
       <apex:repeat value="{!Opportunity.OpportunityLineItems}" var="line">
          <tr>
             <td>{!line.PricebookEntry.Name}</td>
             <td>{!line.Description}</td>
             <td ALIGN="center"><img src='{!line.PricebookEntry.Product2.URL_Picture__c}'/></td>             
             <td>{!line.Quantity}</td>
             <td><apex:OutputField value="{!line.UnitPrice}"/></td>
             <td><apex:OutputField value="{!line.TotalPrice}"/></td>
          </tr>
       </apex:repeat>  
</tr>
<tr>
       <td bgcolor="#C0C0C0" align="right" colspan="6">
       <font face="Arial"><b>Total:</b>&nbsp;<apex:OutputField value="{!Opportunity.Amount}"/></font></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: The `tr` wrapping the `apex:repeat` is incorrect. It should not be there. If it's in the lab that way, the lab is wrong. It generates code like `<tr><tr><td>...</td></tr></tr>`

Comment: I cut straight from the Force.com Labs code, which renders beautifully.  You are missing the fact that there is formatting.  First and last TR blocks have special formatting, different from center TR block.

Comment: "`<tr>`: Permitted content; Zero or more `<td>` or `<th>` elements, or a mix of them. (--MDN)" No other elements are permitted within a `<tr>` as direct descendents (other than global elements, such as comments), so this code renders incorrect HTML5.

Comment: Renders beautifully on an iPad.  Renders beautifully on a PC, so it works the way I need it to.  If I ever experience problems with it, I will check the AppExchange for any code corrections.

Comment: I'm not arguing that modern browsers won't render it. I'm arguing against going against HTML5 standards because you want an extra `<tr>` tag "because that's what the lab had in it." It's code like this why browsers are slower than they have to be-- they have to account for developers that can't follow the standards.

Comment: I'm just trying to help someone out by quoting some free code from a fully working unmanaged app on the AppExchange.  If you have a problem with the skills of the individual who wrote the code, which works, take it up with him and stop shooting at the messenger.  You can post your concerns on the AppExchange feedback if you like.

Comment: Your help is appreciated; nobody's arguing that point. I'm simply advocating that posting syntaxically correct code should be preferred over a carbon copy of bad code. Proliferation of bad habits is never good. For example, `String[] someList = new String[0]; someList.clear();` isn't invalid Apex Code, and it runs, but it bogs down the code.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12031/discussion-between-snugsfbay-and-sfdcfox)

Comment: Checked the code using docType="xhtml-1.0" as you suggested and found that it did still work fine.  The TR may be unnecessary, but it does not appear to cause problems.

Comment: From chat: I forgot that it's legal to not close a TR tag, so the result is you get extra, blank table rows. This might be a problem with some style sheets.

Comment: The quantity & placement of tr tags aside, this doesn't quite fit my use case, because I don't want a row per item, I want (ed) a cell per item, 3 cells per row, up to the  maximum of 9 items/cells that my controller might return. Ie, I don't know where the row breaks will be in the series - I could have 1 3 5, 6 7 8 or 1 2 4, 5 6 7, 8 9. That's why panel grid was appealing - you set the # of columns and it renders the rows for you.